# BASH: setting a variable (potentially multiple values) depending on what other variable starts with

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

I am trying to set the `$Environment` variable depending on what `$EnvironmentGroup` is set to. I thought combining `until` and `if` would work, but I end up with an empty variable. Any help is appreciated :)

```
until [ -n $Environment ]
  do
    if [ $EnvironmentGroup -eq ^dev* ]
    then Environment=dev
    break
    fi
    if [ $EnvironmentGroup -eq ^sit* ]
    then Environment=sit
    break
    fi
    if [ $EnvironmentGroup -eq ^uat* ]
    then Environment=uat
    break
    fi
    if [ $EnvironmentGroup -eq ^prod* ]
    then Environment=prod
    break
    fi
done
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what prompted to use `until` in this case.  Nevertheless, you don't really need a loop here or even multiple conditions.  You could make use of the binary operator `=~`:

```
[[ $EnvironmentGroup =~ ^(dev|sit|uat|prod) ]] && Environment="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

This would set `Environment` depending on what `EnvironmentGroup` starts with (of the 4 given options).

Moreover, you cannot use *globs* in the test, i.e. `[`, condition.

Quoting from the manual:

> Substrings  matched  by  parenthesized  subexpressions  within the regular
>          expression are saved in the array variable `BASH_REMATCH`.   The  element
>          of  `BASH_REMATCH` with index 0 is the portion of the string matching the
>          entire regular expression.  The element of `BASH_REMATCH` with index n is
>          the portion of the string matching the nth parenthesized subexpression.

Comment: I believe you need to take out `*` from the regex

Comment: This seems to work well! Could you explain the "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" part?

Comment: @anubhava What makes you think so?

Comment: Because this is not glob pattern and your regex will even match an empty string.

Comment: @user3558925 The `BASH_REMATCH` array contains substrings matched ...  Refer to the edit above.

Comment: You just need: **`[[ "$EnvironmentGroup" =~ ^(dev|sit|uat|prod) ]] && Environment="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"`**

Comment: @anubhava Obvious fails to occur!

Comment: @anubhava BTW, the variant suffixed with `.*` does __not__ match an empty string.  `[[ $EnvironmentGroup =~ ^(dev|sit|uat|prod).* ]] && echo y` with the variable in question being set to an empty string wouldn't produce anything.

Comment: Yes you're right `^(dev|sit|uat|prod).*` won't match empty string

Answer (score 2):

The question is tagged bash, but if someone needed a more posixly-correct solution here is one possibility:

```
 case $EnvironmentGroup in
  prod*) Environment=prod;;
  dev*|sit*|uat*) Environment=${EnvironmentGroup%${EnvironmentGroup#???}}
 esac
```